# On click same li id need to remove class

Tags: jquery

I have a code that will add a class to #listview-userlist li if its clicked.

This one is working like supposed to be..

Now i want it to remove the added class="selected" if clicking again on the same selected name

```
$('#listview-userlist').on('click','li',function(evt){
    $('#listview-userlist li').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

Comment: What issue are you having? Is there an error message? What have you already tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$('#listview-userlist').on('click', 'li', function (evt) {
    $('#listview-userlist li').not(this).removeClass('selected');
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/xJhE9/)**

First you remove the selected class from all the li elements except the one you clicked on. Then you simply toggle the class on the list item you did click on.

Comment: Can you make this work if click again on "a" without clicking "b" to remove the class

Comment: It works that way now. Sorry, the link was to the wrong fiddle. Updated.